# Ng-hide ng-show or routing to show edit/add form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ng-show, ng-hide

Imagine an application has a List page, such as a table showing a list of users. There is a button on each row of the table called "Edit", and when this is clicked, a right-panel appears on the right-side of the browser with the form to edit that user's contents. When the form is saved or is closed, the right-side panel disappears.
I see that some people use ng-hide/ng-show to show/hide the edit form and others use routing.
My question is what is the best approach and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on what you want. When you choose to go with routing, you can bookmark that page, since you have a full URL. But when you choose to work with   `nghide/ngshow` you can't.

Instead of using `ngshow/ng-hide`, you could also think about using `ng-if`. The difference is that `ng-if` removes the HTML fromt the Dom tree. So, imagine you have 100 items in the list and you use `ng-hide/ng-show` all the data is loaded into the Dom tree. But when using `ng-if` the required html is only appended to the dom when necessary.

Comment: I have only one form with ng-model. When the edit button of a row is clicked I bind a selectedModel variable passing the item of the row, that fills the fields of the form with ng-model. But yes, ng-if it's an option as well.

Comment: In that case I would go for `ng-if` directive. You have everything in place for it and to reduce the size of the DOM I would go for `ng-if`

Comment: So, if the edit were in another page (supposing that I want to hide the list and only show the form) do you suggest to use routing?

Comment: Yes, when the edit page is a separate page, I would create a new route for it.

Answer (score 0):

ng-show / ng-hide is used when you have the template included in your html but just want to show/hide based on some condition.

routing is used to go to a separate html altogether.

Since Add/Edit is a separate functionality then showing the list, ideally these forms should be shown in a separate page. But it depends on how the UI is designed.

You can use routing for ADD/Edit forms or ng-show/ng-hide.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you want to use show/hide. You want the rest of the list to still be there while you're editing one entry, and when you save that entry you want to go right back to the list view. You can do something like `ng-show="edit_object != null"` for your edit form, and when you click on an edit button, you set `$scope.edit_object=row` and populate the inputs of your form with the content of the object you want to edit. When you save or close the edit form, you can set `$scope.edit_object=null`.